# Bndtools and org.osgi.util.tracker package

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, bndtools

I'm using Bndtools in Eclipse IDE. It's great and works fine.
I'm able to add osgi.core package into the "Build Path" editing the bnd file (it uses the bndtools repositories).
Now I need the org.osgi.util.tracker package but I can't find it in the "Build Path" editing the bnd file.
How can I do it ?

Thanks,
Paolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.osgi.util.tracker` is a package but in the Java compiler we need to put whole JARs on the build classpath.

This package happens to come from the bundle/JAR called `osgi.cmpn`, which represents the OSGi Compendium specifications. So just add `osgi.cmpn` to the `-buildpath` of your bnd.bnd file and the package you want will be visible.

If you don't know what JAR/bundle a package comes from, you can use the Advanced Search button in the Repositories View in Bndtools. If you can't find it there then you will have to go and get the JAR from the outside world and import it into your repository. Just googling for the package name will usually tell you the name of the library you need.

Comment: Yes I know about org.osgi.util.tracket isn't a jar but a package but I didn't know about the great advanced search feature ;-) Thanks !

Comment: Actually org.osgi.util.tracker now comes in osgi.core.

Comment: Okay by "now" I suppose you mean R6. So an option is to add `osgi.core; version=6` to your -buildpath.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [OSGi enRoute][1] then you'll find that you only need to compile against the base API JAR (all enRoute projects are so setup). This makes your life a lot easier. The base API contains all API (and ONLY API) for the most common tasks from the most humble 'Hello World' to a REST server with Web User Interface.

[1] http://enroute.osgi.org